# Blue imp jquery file upload edit option not showing

Tags: php, jquery

I am using Blue imp file upload plugin from  git hub  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

I have downloaded the package  and run on local , but unable to  see the edit option as I can see their demo . Can anyone please help me with that .

Answer (score 0):

For the "Edit Option" you need the javascript library "doka", which is not free available. More about Doka you can find here:

https://pqina.nl/pintura/